# How do I get my Acer C720 to boot into 12.04 Cinnamon on startup?

Tags: boot, startup, cinnamon

I have successfully installed 12.04 and it works great. I just want to startup into 12.04.

I have tried this command:

```
sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda
```

But it is not working. I still boot into Chrome.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you mean by "12.04" Cinnamon? Where are you getting the commands you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to install Ubuntu on a chromebook, here is the best guide to doing so:

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343

I am not sure where you got the commands you are running, but I suggest starting over and following that guide.

Comment: I used this...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGvC0TWPk-g

Comment: Never use youtube for anything important. Go read.